# The Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password comes up when trying to upload files to SharePoint by a python script

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, authentication, python

I am trying to upload files to a SharePoint folder structure which has been already created, I have used two files for this
Config_template:

```
config = dict()
config['sp_user'] = 'abs@xyz.com'
config['sp_password'] = 'pass@123'
config['sp_base_path'] = 'https://xyz.sharepoint.com'
config['sp_site_name'] = '/sites/bootromandhsesecurity/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?originalPath=0d66ed181f1&id=%2Fsites%2Fbootromandhsesecurity%2FShared%20Documents%2F%2FSprint3'
config['sp_doc_library'] = 'Sprint3'
```

The next file is sharepoint_upload:

```
import requests
from shareplum import Office365
from .config_template import config
def up():
    # get data from configuration
    username = config['sp_user']
    password = config['sp_password']
    site_name = config['sp_site_name']
    base_path = config['sp_base_path']
    doc_library = config['sp_doc_library']

    file_name = "TestCaseDatabase\\Sprint3_Test_Report.xlsx"

    # Obtain auth cookie
    authcookie = Office365(base_path, username=username, password=password).GetCookies()
    session = requests.Session()
    session.cookies = authcookie
    session.headers.update({'user-agent': 'python_bite/v1'})
    session.headers.update({'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'})

   
    session.headers.update({'X-RequestDigest': 'FormDigestValue'})
    response = session.post( url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + doc_library + "')/Files/add(url='a.txt',overwrite=true)",
                            data="")
    session.headers.update({'X-RequestDigest': response.headers['X-RequestDigest']})

    # perform the actual upload
    with open( file_name, 'rb') as file_input:
        try: 
            response = session.post( 
                url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + doc_library + "')/Files/add(url='" 
                + file_name + "',overwrite=true)",
                data=file_input)
        except Exception as err: 
            print("Some error occurred: " + str(err))
```

The username and password have been changed here for security reasons, but when the correct details have been given,

> Error authenticating against Office 365. Error from Office 365:', 'AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password

The above error occurs. Where am I going wrong?

P.S - I have been using Microsoft authenticator for logging into the SharePoint folder, where I need to approve my login on my mobile, is that causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with Python, but my experience with connecting sharepoint with MFA enabled account is that you removed the Password parameter from the code.

On executing the Powershell/code (without password parameter), a pop up will come to provide the credentials and MFA unique code.

give it try..